# Which probability measure book is more comprehensive?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, reference-request, reference-works

I have read Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis. I am now choosing one of the 2 books:

Probability and Measure by **Patrick Billingsley**

OR

Probability and Measure Theory by **Robert Ash**

I have tried to find all the sources on the Internet (e.g, amazon,..) to find which book is better. However, all of them said that both are well-written books, so I do not know which one to choose because I do not have time and want to read a comprehensive and detailed book.

Could you please give me some advice? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I go with the second book.